# python matplotlib backend configuration

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, anaconda, pythonplotter

I just installed Intel Python Distribution with Anaconda. I was trying the plot some data but it plots on Web Browser and gives "Press Ctrl+C to stop WebAgg server" output also. I tried to change the backend using "plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')" and it worked and plotted in standard GUI Tkinter as I wanted. However I want to change the default configs of matplotlib not to put "plt.switch_backend('TkAgg')" everytime I plot something. Do you know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would hope that is clear from the [Customizing tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html), but if setting the backend in the rc file does not help, there might be a setting overwriting it, in which case more information would be needed to where and how you run things.

Comment: Thank you @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for your comment, as you said I have found the matplotlibrc file and changed the backend value in it as TkAgg and it worked.